# record is not updating when i use a call function that does the update

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a an unbound form that with a button that adds new record to a table. It is perfectly working but, now i want to use a sub function (newAddition) that handles the real work and just call it whenever i need but i discover that it is only showing blank fields in the main table when i try to save a new record.

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("T_MASTER")

  Dim Checker As Integer
  Dim Duplicate_Checker As Integer

  Dim code, prodname, QP1_combo, QP1_name, QP1_CAS, txt_component_Type, txt_CONTENT_Lower_limit, BEARBEITER As String
  Dim CONTENT, Informationsquelle, Anzahl_Partner, Anhange, Kommentar, end_datum, datum_kunde, datum_dossier, compedium As Variant
  Dim CONTENT_Upper_limit, Bearb_Start_Partner, Bearb_End_Partner, profile As Variant
  Dim Date_of_entry, Bearb_Start_Datum, Bearb_End_Datum As Variant

  Checker = 0
  Duplicate_Checker = 0

  '*******************************************************
  'Verify that the essential fields have values.
  '*******************************************************
If IsNull(Me.txt_code.Value) Then
    Checker = MsgBox("Product code cannot be empty", vbOKOnly, "Error")
           Me.txt_code.SetFocus
ElseIf IsNull(Me.txt_prodname.Value) Then

    Checker = MsgBox("Please enter the product name", vbOKOnly, "Error")
          Me.txt_prodname.SetFocus
ElseIf IsNull(Me.txt_QP1_combo.Value) Then
    Checker = MsgBox("Please select PURE QP1.", vbOKOnly, "Error")
            Me.txt_QP1_combo.SetFocus
ElseIf IsNull(Me.txt_component_Type.Value) Then
    Checker = MsgBox("Please select the component type.", vbOKOnly, "Error")
              Me.txt_component_Type.SetFocus
    ElseIf IsNull(Me.txt_BEARBEITER.Value) Then
    Checker = MsgBox("Please fill the bearbeiter field.", vbOKOnly, "Error")
              Me.txt_BEARBEITER.SetFocus
    End If

'*******************************************************
  'Checking for duplicacies in the database.
'*******************************************************
   code = Me.txt_code.Value
   QP1_combo = Me.txt_QP1_combo.Value

If Checker = 0 Then

     Do While Not rs.EOF
      If rs("PRODUCT_CODE") = code And rs("PURE_QP1") = QP1_combo Then

      Duplicate_Checker = MsgBox("Record already in the database!", vbOKOnly, "Duplicate")

       End If
       rs.MoveNext
   Loop

   End If

   '*******************************************************
  ' Reading the values.
  '*******************************************************

If Checker = 0 And Duplicate_Checker = 0 Then

 prodname = Me.txt_prodname.Value

 QP1_name = Me.txt_QP1_name.Value
 QP1_CAS = Me.txt_QP1_CAS.Value
 Component_Type = Me.txt_component_Type.Value
 CONTENT = Me.txt_content.Value
 CONTENT_Lower_limit = Me.txt_CONTENT_Lower_limit.Value
 CONTENT_Upper_limit = Me.txt_CONTENT_upper_limit.Value
 'Date_of_entry = Me.txt_Date_of_entry.Value
 BEARBEITER = Me.txt_BEARBEITER.Value
 Bearb_Start_Datum = Me.txt_Bearb_Start_Datum.Value
 Bearb_Start_Partner = Me.txt_Bearb_Start_Partner.Value
 Bearb_End_Datum = Me.txt_Bearb_End_Datum.Value

 Bearb_End_Partner = Me.txt_Bearb_End_Partner.Value
 Anzahl_Partner = Me.txt_Anzahl_Partner.Value
 Informationsquelle = Me.txt_Informationsquelle.Value
 Anhange = Me.txt_Anhange.Value
 Kommentar = Me.txt_Kommentar.Value
 datum_kunde = Me.txt_datum_kunde.Value
 datum_dossier = Me.txt_datum_dossier.Value
 profile = Me.txt_profile.Value
 compedium = Me.txt_compedium.Value
 '*******************************************************
  'Updating the database.
  '*******************************************************
  NewAddition
  MsgBox ("Record successfully saved")
  End If
End Sub`
```

And this is the sub function

```
 Sub NewAddition()
 Dim db As Database
 Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

 Set db = CurrentDb
 Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("T_MASTER")

 rs.AddNew
 rs("PRODUCT_CODE") = code
 rs("PRODUCT_NAME") = prodname
 rs("PURE_QP1").Value = QP1_combo
 rs("PURE_NAME_QP1").Value = QP1_name
 rs("PURE_CAS_NR").Value = QP1_CAS
 rs("Component_Type").Value = Component_Type
 rs("CONTENT").Value = CONTENT
 rs("CONTENT_lower limit").Value = CONTENT_Lower_limit
 rs("CONTENT_upper limit").Value = CONTENT_Upper_limit
 rs("Date_of_entry").Value = Date
 rs("BEARBEITER").Value = BEARBEITER
 rs("Bearb_Start_Datum").Value = Bearb_Start_Datum
 rs("Bearb_Start_Partner").Value = Bearb_Start_Partner
 rs("Bearb_End_Datum").Value = Bearb_End_Datum
 rs("Bearb_End_Partner").Value = Bearb_End_Partner
 rs("Anzahl_Partner").Value = Anzahl_Partner
 rs("Informationsquelle").Value = Informationsquelle
 rs("Anhänge").Value = Anhange
 rs("Kommentar").Value = Kommentar
 rs("Datum_Statement_Kunde").Value = datum_kunde
 rs("Datum_Statement_Dossier").Value = datum_dossier
 rs("Profile_Y_N").Value = profile
 rs("Compendium_Y_N").Value = compedium
'   rs("Thema").Value = topic
 rs.Update
 End Sub
```

If i click the button, it brings the prompt, record successfully saved as in the code but doesn't write anyting there. It only creates blank records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are declared and set locally - they only exist for procedure they are declared in. They are killed when procedure ends. Need to declare variables in module header or use some other method to pass data to other procedure.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim code, prodname, QP1_combo, QP1_name, QP1_CAS, txt_component_Type, txt_CONTENT_Lower_limit, BEARBEITER As String
Dim CONTENT, Informationsquelle, Anzahl_Partner, Anhange, Kommentar, end_datum, datum_kunde, datum_dossier, compedium As Variant
Dim CONTENT_Upper_limit, Bearb_Start_Partner, Bearb_End_Partner, profile As Variant
Dim Date_of_entry, Bearb_Start_Datum, Bearb_End_Datum As Variant
__________________________________________________________________________________

Private Sub Command0_Click()
...
```

VBA requires every variable type to be explicitly declared or it will default to Variant. So on line where you have `BEARBEITER As String`, only BEARBEITER is a string type, others on that line are Variant. They will work regardless.

Comment: i understood what you meant but I dont know to pass variable value from one procedure to the other

Comment: See revised answer. Declare variables in module header. Set variables in first procedure. Reference variables in second procedure. BTW, neither of these procedures is a 'function'.

Comment: I have added option explicit which is now making it to be showing error of undeclared variable in the second procedure. how do <i reference the variable in the second procedure.?

Comment: Did you declare variables in module header as shown?